# Can "X3DH" instead of HMQV be used for OPAQUE?

Tags: protocol-design, key-exchange

So I recently re-read [the OPAQUE paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/163) and while reading it I found HMQV to be a bit "unnatural" / "unintuitive", which may just be because I didn't (yet) read the HMQV paper, so I wondered whether one could replace the instantiation of the key-exchange with the X3DH primitive<sup>*</sup>.

So this is my question:
**In OPAQUE, can we replace the instatiation of "KE" with the below X3DH primitve?**

Or asked differently (but equivalently!) per the requirements in the paper:
**Is X3DH AKE-KCI secure (and if not can this be easily fixed)?**

---

`*`: ie we compute $\operatorname{KE}(x_u,p_u,X_s,P_s)=H(X_s^{x_u}\parallel X_s^{p_u}\parallel P_s^{x_u})$ with the $x$ being ephemeral private / public DH keys and the $p$ being static private / public DH keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current [IETF draft for OPAQUE](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-irtf-cfrg-opaque-10.html#name-online-authenticated-key-exc) specifies using the 3DH protocol to instantiate the AKE subprotocol.

As for the actual X3DH protocol itself, it has been shown to provide security against Key Compromise Impersonation attacks. In [A Formal Security Analysis of the Signal Messaging Protocol](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/1013), the security of the signal protocol in a variant of the Multi-Stage Key Exchange model of [Fischlin and Günther](https://www.felixguenther.info/publications/CCS_FisGue14.pdf). They show KCI security in a model where attackers may reveal long-term secrets and ephemeral randomness.

At a high-level, KCI security is guaranteed as long as the attacker doesn't compromise both the ephemeral secret of the initiator and the prekey of the receiver. This attack was shown first mentioned by [Kobeissi, Bhargavan and Blanchet](https://bblanche.gitlabpages.inria.fr/publications/KobeissiBhargavanBlanchetEuroSP17.pdf). However, they consider a variant of signal and also KCI attacks usually only assume compromise of long-term secrets.